# Use click event in Angular + Openlayers to detect the layer clicked

Tags: angular, openlayers, geoserver

I need to know what layer I am clicking in an openlayers map to grab some data of it later.

I've made it before but only using one layer. Now I have more than one and I would like to know what layer I'm clicking to grab its information from geoserver.

```ts
capa1WMS:TileLayer;
map:Map;

...

getDatosCapaWMS(url:string): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(url);
}

clickMapa(event:any):void{
    if(this.capa1WMS.getSource()!=null){
      var url = this.capa1WMS.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        this.map.getEventCoordinate(event), this.view.getResolution(), this.view.getProjection(),
        {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'});
      this.getDatosCapaWMS(url).subscribe(data => { 

        //stuff

    });
    }   
}
```

And my HTML code

```html
<div id="map" class="map" (click)="clickMapa($event)"></div>
```

I have seen that openlayers has a method called `forEachFeatureAtPixel()` but I haven't made it work

Comment: Use `this.map.forEachLayerAtPixel(event.pixel)` to get the layers to use for `.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl()`

Comment: event.pixel is not a property of the event, so I obtain an error while calling the forEachLayerAtPixel() function. Do you know another way to obtain that pixel?

Comment: Please try: this.map.forEachLayerAtPixel([e.layerX, e.layerY])

Comment: in connection with: document.addEventListener('click', ...

Comment: Use `map.getEventPixel(event)` instead of `event.pixel` if you use the div click event.  Most code uses OpenLayers own click handler `this.map.on('singleclick', clickMapa);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Mike gave the solution

`this.map.forEachLayerAtPixel(this.map.getEventPixel(event))` to get the layers to use for `.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl()`